# Replace join function using Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, join

I have the following dataframes :

```
Dataframe1
+---------------+
|id_data        |
+---------------+
|[1,20,3]       |
|[5,40]         |
|[50,90]        |
|[30,70]        |
+---------------+
```

Type of id_data : `array<integer>`

```
Dataframe2
+---------------+
|id_data2       |
+---------------+
|20             |
|90             |
|100            |
+---------------+
```

I want the following output :

```
 +---------------+
 |id_data2       |
 +---------------+
 |20             |
 |90             |
 +---------------+
```

I did that using `join`

```
 Dataset <Row> result =  Dataframe2.as("data1").join( Dataframe1.as("data2"),expr("array_contains(data2.id_data,data1.id_data2)"));
```

I have a large amount of data and it is very heavy in terms of performance.

There is any posibility to do that without `join function` using Spark with java language ?

I need your help .

Comment: join is needed but you can `explode` the first one.

Comment: I did some research and Ifound that I can read the values of Dataframe 1 as a String Variables .

Comment: like that : `for(Iterator<Row> iter = dataframee.toLocalIterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            String item = (iter.next()).get(0).toString();
        }` and doing tat : `select *from Dataframe2 where id_data2 = item`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `explode` function. This is a Scala code.

```
df1.withColumn("id_data1", explode($"id_data"))
  .join(df2, $"id_data1" === $"id_data2", "inner")
  .select("id_data1")
  .show

+--------+
|id_data1|
+--------+
|      20|
|      90|
+--------+
```